# App doesn't start in my phone, however, debugger/logcat/console shows no errors at all

Tags: android, crash, version

I'm learning to program in Android Studio. I have finished a Hang man game, with audio and video included. My only concern is that my app isn't starting in phones below Android 7. I have created the proyect to work with versions above of Android 4. In my gradle I have:  minSdkVersion 15 and targetSdkVersion 26. But for some reason, it crashes in phones that are below Android 7.

Anyone have experienced this before? I have tried to compile the APK in a different computer with another installation of Android Studio, but the output is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move everything in Drawable-v24 to Drawable.